# Exporting default RStudio themes, or setting parenthesis colour?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to customise my RStudio theme, which is easy enough using https://tmtheme-editor.glitch.me/

One of the default themes is *so nearly* perfect for my particular colourblindness and all I want to do is tweak the contrast a bit, but it doesn't exist in the gallery in the editor (yes, I'm sure), and I can't find a way to set the parentheses to have a distinct colour. This is definitely possible and RStudio definitely supports it, because Material [nb, not the same as [this Material theme](https://github.com/material-theme/vsc-material-theme)], one of their default themes does this and it's incredibly useful:

Screenshot of RStudio's theme-picker showing the theme 'Material' which has red parentheses:

[image]

However, the [various](https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/guide/ui/appearance.html#creating-an-rstheme) [guides](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio-theme-creation.html) I can find for making R themes don't include this as an option.

I've been trying to export this theme from RStudio so I can upload it and just tweak the colours, or edit the CSS direcrly, but I can't find a way to do that. *User-installed* themes can be found in the config files [as described here](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio-theme-creation.html), but not the themes that came with RStudio in the first place

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/87e129853121106a87e92df416363f39da95f82e/src/cpp/session/resources/themes/material.rstheme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find the file you want in `RStudio/resources/themes/material.rstheme`. In particular, line 138 shows

```r
.ace_paren.ace_keyword.ace_operator {
  color: #cc6666 !important;
}
```

This gives us a CSS hook to change the color of parentheses in an RStudio theme. We can change it to yellow, for example:

```r
.ace_paren.ace_keyword.ace_operator {
  color: #ffff30 !important;
}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]